# iptables port forward forwarding

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm trying to do some simple tcp port forwarding

```
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# /bin/echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW
tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW
tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW
tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW
tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW
tcp dpt:https
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --proto
tcp --dport 80 --jump DNAT --to 10.52.208.223:80
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# iptables --table nat --list PREROUTING
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp
dpt:http to:10.52.208.223:80
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# curl --verbose http://10.52.208.221:80
* About to connect() to 10.52.208.221 port 80
*   Trying 10.52.208.221... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]#
```

Comment: Is the web service on 10.52.208.223 actually running?

Comment: yes, webserver on .223 is running no problem

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the traffic to 10.52.208.221. Given the config you posted, your problem is the webserver, not the firewall. Your rules look to be correct. FORWARD and INPUT are redirected to RH-Firewall-1-INPUT where your first rule is to allow all traffic. As somebody else pointed out, you could be allowing all traffic on eth1, while the world is actually coming in eth0. Secondary, you have to NAT the traffic as it goes back out to the world

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --proto tcp --dport 80 --jump MASQUERADE -o OUT_INTERFACE
```

Your traffic originating from the router will never hit the input or forward chains, but instead traverse the output chain on to the webserver. Other systems in that subnet will similarly go directly to the webserver. Systems out on the world at large however will traverse the INPUT / FORWARD chains and need SNAT as well as DNAT so that it appears to the world to be one machine. You still cannot test from within your network. you must test from the opposite interface from the webserver. Get me your IP addresses and I'll point you to the proper configs.

Comment: webserver *is* running and by hitting .221 it should redirec / serve from .223 and even though that rule seems to be fine, its not working!

Comment: You can't do that, you have to request http://10.52.208.221 from another machine, not the system acting as a firewall.

Comment: Richard June is correct. You are on the same subnet as the destination so no routing is happening and the PREROUTING rules aren't being hit. BTW whenever I use `iptables` I use the verbose option. It shows the interfaces to which the rules apply and, which is helpful in this case, the number of packets that matched each rule. E.g., `iptables --table nat --list PREROUTING --verbose`

Comment: Richard, could you update your main answer?

Answer (score 0):

Getting a connection refused means that at least a host is accepting the TCP packets, but no service is listening on that port. What happens when you connect from a different IP to both 10.52.208.221:80 and to 10.52.208.223?

I can't test it right now, but I've seen some scenarios where connecting from the host where the IP tables are set to a NAT'ed IP doesn't work. I'm not sure if that's the case here, since you don't explicitly define an interface where the rule is applied to, but I've seen some cases where Linux sees the IP you want to connect to as "local" and using the loopback interface and skipping iptables.

Anyway, can you try it from outside of the box?